# How to Integrate StartApp Search box and Apps list into my App?

Tags: android, startapp

I have seen StartApp Search box and Apps list in someone's app and i have searched how to integrate. But i canot find anything about it.
here is the screen shot - 
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw9ug.png)

Anyone knows please help.
Thank You